# Rounding down only if the third decimal digit equals to 5

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to make a formula for if the the third decimal digit is 5, round it down otherwise only round. Is it possible please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome! Are you only talking about positive values? Then just subtract 0.001 before rounding. If you also talking about negative numbers, then a clarification is really required - "round down" this floor towards zero or towards minus infinity?

Comment: I commend to your attention the [discussion on AbleBits of rounding in Excel](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-round-functions/).

Comment: You should provide more information about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) requires a tie-breaking rule, i.e. its easy to round to the closest significant digit but what to do at half way point, where both the upper and lower significant digits are equally close. The most widely used tie-breaking rule is called "half up" meaning 0.5 rounds to 1, even though 0 is equally close by.

It seems you wish to implement the "half down" rule, then in its most basic form:

```
=IF(ABS(A1*100 - TRUNC(A1*100)) = 0.5,ROUNDDOWN(A1,2), ROUND(A1,2))
```

or optimised for less comparative operations

```
=TRUNC(A1*100)/100 + IF(ABS(A1*100 - TRUNC(A1*100)) <= 0.5, 0, sign(A1)*0.01)
```

Comment: Another option for half down based on the 3rd decimal place would be `=IF(RIGHT(TRUNC(A1*1000))="5",ROUNDDOWN(A1,2),ROUND(A1,2))`

Comment: Oh the Excel blasphemy @EngineerToast :) Yes it will work, but converting a number to text and then doing a text comparison is very inefficient. Something like `=IF(MOD(TRUNC(H28*1000),10)=5,ROUNDDOWN(A1,2),ROUND(A1,2))` is quite neat - but MOD is probably more inefficient than the text detour!

Comment: Beware, kids, this is what happens when you spend too much time on PPCG and start focusing on efficiency of bytes instead of efficiency of operations.

Comment: @EngineerToast btw is there code golfing in excel?

Comment: There are around 1,000 answers on PPCG that are in Excel according to either [the basic search](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=+is%3Aanswer+%22Excel%22) or the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/revision/1665202/2027057/excel-answers).

Answer (score 0):

ROUND will round 5 up.  so minus `0.001` from the value and that way anything that has `#.##5` will round down.

```
=ROUND(A1-0.001,3)
```

This will round anything that has 5 in the third decimal down regardless of the other decimals beyond it.  If the intention is to round down anything Excel would round to `#.##5` then we subtract `0.0005` instead.

```
=ROUND(A1-0.0005,3)
```

Now if A1 could be negative we can use SIGN():

```
=ROUND(A1-(SIGN(A1)*0.0005,3)
```

Comment: This will work as long as the numbers are positive and the value you subtract is smaller than the smallest difference between the actual value and x.xx5. E.g. 0.0551 should round up, but 0.0551 - 0.001 = 0.0541 will round down. Changing the formula to e.g. `=ROUND(A1-0.000001,3)` should work.

Comment: As I understood the question the OP wanted anything that was `#.##5` to round down regardless of the decimals after it.  If the true cut of is `#.##549` then we subtract `0.0005`

Comment: And as to the negative, see edit.